# How to Run Laravel Route Constrains Before Middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have route something like this **/permissions/{uuid}** And I have route constrain and middleware.

Constraint Rule: Add in route service provider for all routes it will apply.

```
Route::pattern('uuid', '[a-f0-9]{8}-?[a-f0-9]{4}-?4[a-f0-9]{3}-?[89ab][a-f0-9]{3}-?[a-f0-9]{12}');
```

Middleware Rule:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $uuid = $request->route('uuid');

    // Check the uuid in DB and throw an exception

    return $next($request);
}
```

But the problem here was the middleware was running first. I just want to avoid db call if uuid was not a proper format. Can we run constrain rule first.

Edit:
It seems something wrong with the global constrain when i use in route leavel its working fine.

Comment: Middleware runs BEFORE the request enters the respective controller method. And thus, this is always OUTSIDE the real application. No controller method is executed unless all the Middlewares are passing the request. You can validate the $uuid  in side the middleware

Answer (score 1):

When Laravel receives a request it will initially pipe it through the global middleware and then try to find the route that matches the request. If it does find a matching route it will then run any middleware that you've specified for it in your routes file, controller constructor etc., resolve any method parameters for the route and then execute the method.
If it doesn't find a matching route it will pretty much just 404.

`Route::pattern(...)` essentially adds a global where clause for that parameter.

So, in your case if you have a `Route` that has `{uuid}` as a parameter it will only be matched if the `uuid` part of the URI matches the pattern provided to `Route::pattern`. Therefore, if you try and go to a url with something that isn't in the correct format it won't match the request to that route and will result in a 404 (unless you have a fallback or another route that would match).

---

Example:

```
Route::pattern('uuid', '[a-f0-9]{8}-?[a-f0-9]{4}-?4[a-f0-9]{3}-?[89ab][a-f0-9]{3}-?[a-f0-9]{12}');
```

```
Route::get('test/{uuid}', 'SomeController@method');
```

This would pass:

```
example.com/test/cfb81fde-9ce6-4a5e-8ddc-38417ef5425c
```

This would cause a 404:

```
example.com/test/1
```

Comment: @vijaykumar Did this answer you question or do you still need help?